# Python variables not defined after if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing, global, program-entry-point

I'm trying to divvy up the task of looking up historical stock price data for a list of symbols by using `Pool` from the `multiprocessing` library.

This works great until I try to use the data I get back.  I have my `hist_price` function defined and it outputs to a list-of-dicts `pcl`.  I can `print(pcl)` and it has been flawless, but if I try to `print(pcl)` after the `if __name__=='__main__':` block, it blows up saying `pcl` is undefined.  I've tried declaring `global pcl` in a couple places but it doesn't make a difference.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

syms = ['List', 'of', 'symbols']

def hist_price(sym):
    #... lots of code looking up data, calculations, building dicts...
    stlh = {"Sym": sym, "10D Max": pcmax, "10D Min": pcmin} #simplified
    return stlh

#global pcl
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(4)
    #global pcl
    pcl = pool.map(hist_price, syms)
    print(pcl) #this works
    pool.close() 
    pool.join()

print(pcl) #says pcl is undefined

#...rest of my code, dependent on pcl...
```

I've also tried removing the `if __name__=='__main__':` block but it gives me a RunTimeError telling me specifically to put it back.  Is there some other way to call variables to use outside of the `if` block?

Comment: Do you have `if __name__=='__main__':` because you're running the script from the terminal or some other reason?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Probably because OP is using multiprocessing.

Comment: @poke oh Ok. apparently so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two parts to your issue. The first is "what's wrong with `pcl` in the current code?", and the second is "why do I need the `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard block at all?".

Lets address them in order. The problem with the `pcl` variable is that it is only defined in the `if` block, so if the module gets loaded without being run as a script (which is what sets `__name__ == "__main__"`), it will not be defined when the later code runs.

To fix this, you can change how your code is structured. The simplest fix would be to guard the other bits of the code that use `pcl` within an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block too (e.g. indent them all under the current block, perhaps). An alternative fix would be to put the code that uses `pcl` into functions (which can be declared outside the guard block), then call the functions from within an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. That would look something like this:

```
def do_stuff_with_pcl(pcl):
    print(pcl)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # multiprocessing code, etc
    pcl = ...
    do_stuff_with_pcl(pcl)
```

As for why the issue came up in the first place, the ultimate cause is using the `multiprocessing` module on Windows. You can read about the issue in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows).

When multiprocessing creates a new process for its `Pool`, it needs to initialize that process with a copy of the current module's state. Because Windows doesn't have `fork` (which copies the parent process's memory into a child process automatically), Python needs to set everything up from scratch. In each child process, it loads the module from its file, and if you the module's top-level code tries to create a new `Pool`, you'd have a recursive situation where each of the child process would start spawning a whole new set of child processes of its own.

The `multiprocessing` code has some guards against that, I think (so you won't [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) yourself out of simple carelessness), but you still need to do some of the work yourself too, by using `if __name__ == "__main__"` to guard any code that shouldn't be run in the child processes.

Comment: This process runs near the beginning of my code, and the rest of it is dependent on `pcl`.  I was hoping to avoid placing the entirety of the rest of my code inside the `if` block if I could help it.  I have tried declaring `pcl` (with and without `global`) outside of the `if` block, but it still appears to treat it as two separate instances.

Comment: @wampthing2: I've updated my answer to go into a bit more background about what the issue is and more detail about how to fix it. In sort: Don't do too much stuff at the top level, since you'll need to guard that with `if __name__ == "__main__"`.