# access variables inside if __name__ == "__main__": in the same script

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

assuming I have a python code abc.py

```
import sys

class xyz():

   def __init__(self, xyz)  
       self.xyz='123'

   def process(self):
       print(var)
       # do something with the dictionary var2 and int var3
       # process the var4 panads dataframe
       print(var5)

if __name__ == "__main__":

  var = '123'
  var2 = {'key_a':'value_a'}
  var3 = int(3)
  var4 = a pandas dataframe getting from reading a SQL database

  if len(sys.argv[1]) == 2:
      var5 = sys.argv[1]
  else:
      raise ValueError("error")

  var6 = var5+int(123456)
```

How could I get the var from if **name** == "**main**": ?

I tried the solution here using runpy

[Python variables not defined after if __name__ == '__main__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961284/python-variables-not-defined-after-if-name-main)

```
import runpy
import sys
class xyz():

   runpy.run_module("abc", run_name="__main__")

   def __init__(self, xyz)  
       self.xyz='123'

   def process(self):
       print(var)
       # do something with the dictionary var2 and int var3
       # process the var4 panads dataframe
       print(var5) 

if __name__ == "__main__":

  var = '123'
  var2 = {'key_a':'value_a'}
  var3 = int(3)
  var4 = a pandas dataframe getting from reading a SQL database

  if len(sys.argv[1]) == 2:
      var5 = sys.argv[1]
  else:
      raise ValueError("error")

  var6 = var5+int(123456)
```

Got an error

```
ImportError: No module named abc
```

I am hoping the solution will be as easy as possible as there are a ton of variables with various data types that I need to fetch from this if **name** == "**main**":

Thank you!

Edit:

A lot of good comments saying this doesn't make sense, which I agree in a way. The problem is if I don't put var5 under if **name** == "**main**": the code will fail when I import and initiate the class xyy in other scripts such as test.py like the following

```
import sys

var = '123'
var2 = {'key_a':'value_a'}
var3 = int(3)
var4 = a pandas dataframe getting from reading a SQL database

if len(sys.argv[1]) == 2:
   var5 = sys.argv[1]
else:
   raise ValueError("error")

var6 = var5+int(123456)

class xyz():

   def __init__(self, xyz)  
       self.xyz='123'

   def process(self):
       print(var)
       # do something with the dictionary var2 and int var3
       # process the var4 panads dataframe
       print(var5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Comment: Do you know whatfor this `if name == "main":` is good for? Your questin makes not much sense to me. If you need to capsule some variables., put them into a class as classmembers then you can access them

Comment: unfortunately this is a legacy code and will take a lot of efforts to refactor. If I don't put all these var inside ``` if name == "main": ```   , when I import the class xyz from test.py, it will fail. Because some vars  var inside  ``` if name == "main": ``` are getting from command lines.

Comment: You need a blank __init__.py file inside the folder in order to import other files. Check if that resolves your import issue.

Comment: yes i have a blank __init__.py in the same  folder as abc.py. Forgot to mention it @MichaelHallabrin but still running into the error "ImportError: No module named abc" thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. why are you defining variables in that block if you need to access them from a method?

Comment: @MichaelHallabrin you don't need one, actually

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks. i just added some comments:
"A lot of good comments saying this doesn't make sense, which I agree in a way. The problem is if I don't put var5 under if __name__ == "__main__": the code will fail when I import and initiate the class xyy in other scripts such as test.py."

Comment: @Chubaka yeah, **that's what doesn't make sense**.  How does the code fail, *exactly*?

Comment: the current code will have an error "ImportError: No module named abc" in the line runpy.run_module("abc", run_name="__main__")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asked in a slightly confusing manner, but I think what you're trying to do is something like:

```
import sys

def main( var5 ):
    var  = 1
    var2 = 2
    var3 = 3
    var4 = 4
    var6 = "Var 5 is: " + var5

    class xyz():
       def process(self):
           print(var)
           print(var5)

    xyz().process()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    var5 = sys.argv[1]
    main( var5 )
```

This way, if you launch your file as a script, it can be something like

```
python3 myscript.py "hello"
```

and if you import it from an interactive session it can be something like

```
import myscript
myscript.main( 'hello' )
```

<sub>PS: I've simplified your example slightly, to remove unnecessary clutter adding to the confusion...</sub>

Comment: Thank you! Let me try it. I have never seen this way where a function inside a class

Comment: Hi @tasos the approach works when i run python3 myscript.py "hello"

However, if I want to unit test the function processor in a separated test.py, how can I import the xyz class in this case? Thank you.

Comment: @Chubaka If you want your class to act as a 'unit' (and thus be unit-testable), then your whole approach of making it rely on a global variable is problematic from the start. Instead, define the class external to main, and make it require appropriate initialization, so that you can create an instance in main by initializing it with the relevant variables, rather than rely on the class discovering them as globals.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up making a new class for var, var2, var3, var4 and inherit this new class into the following classes. By doing so, it fulfills the mission and makes the testing in tests.py possible.